# Can I override a folder in a Docker image with a volume from host?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume, docker-run

Given a `Dockerfile` like this:

```
WORKDIR /

COPY ./folder ./folder

# OTHER COMMANDS...
```

On my `dev` environment I would like to override the `./folder` that was copied to the image, by using the real `./folder` on my machine, so I can use `nodemon` from the image and make it **hot reload** with changes.

So if I run this image like this:

```
docker run OTHER_STUFF -v ./folder:/folder IMAGE_NAME
```

Is this the correct approach to override a folder that exists on the image, with an external folder?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the correct way. Only one detail: you must specify the full absolute path on the host i.e.:

```sh
docker run OTHER_STUFF -v /full/path/to/folder:/folder IMAGE_NAME
```

If you want to use relative paths you should use `docker-compose`.